# Sales force application load testing using JMeter, one of the requests has got response of invalid JSON message

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

We are using JMeter for salesforce application performance testing and the request information is sent using parameters and one of the parameters holds the Json message and when we execute the request we are getting  as

/{"event":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:systemError","attributes":{"values":{"message":"[AuraClientInputException from server] Unexpected request input. Expected input format: "Data in a request must be a valid JSON Object and must be in the expected format."."}}

when i have validated the request using Json format validator it is valid json however when take the request sent from the view result tree it is not a valid json, something went wrong or JMeter has modified the message. anybody has faced this issue any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say anything without seeing your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration

Normally if you add your JSON to the "Body Data" tab of the HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

and add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) configured to send [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of `application/json`

[image]

the request should reach the server "as it is"

If you have doubts whether your JMeter setup is correct you can just record the relevant request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)